# A question has occured when installing the C development related components by Visual studio installer

Tags: visual-studio

A question has occured when installing the C development related components by Visual studio installer.It prompts that can't install Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.There is the error code :'PackageId:Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest;PackageAction:Install;ReturnCode:1603;' So can anybody help me?
**In the error log,there are some errors occur**

```
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'Arm64_Check' to value 'AMD64'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting version variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKey' to value '10.0.22000.1'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 1
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to get size of pseudo bundle: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{40d3fee2-b257-46c2-bdc0-cb1088d97327}\VC_redist.x64.exe
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to initialize package from related bundle id: {40d3fee2-b257-46c2-bdc0-cb1088d97327}
```

---

**and**

```
[4688:0880][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0025DD72-A959-45B5-A0A3-7EFEB15A8050}v14.36.32532\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{D5D19E2F-7189-42FE-8103-92CD1FA457C2}v14.36.32532\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:23:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:23:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
```

---

then there is the whole error log,it's a long massage.

```
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i001: Burn v3.10.4.4718, Windows v10.0 (Build 22000: Service Pack 0), path: C:\WINDOWS\Temp\{9F22977D-DE62-4A6D-AB7D-188B8F215F55}\.cr\VC_redist.x64.exe
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=D:\Aporimuse\VScommunity\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.36.32532,chip=x64\VC_redist.x64.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=552 -burn.filehandle.self=672 /q /norestart /log C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.log'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'D:\Aporimuse\VScommunity\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.36.32532,chip=x64\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'D:\Aporimuse\VScommunity\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.36.32532,chip=x64\'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.log'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.36.32532'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[4598:2B80][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '14.36.32532.0'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i100: Detect begin, 11 packages
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'Arm64_Check' to value 'AMD64'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting version variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKey' to value '10.0.22000.1'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 1
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to get size of pseudo bundle: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{40d3fee2-b257-46c2-bdc0-cb1088d97327}\VC_redist.x64.exe
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to initialize package from related bundle id: {40d3fee2-b257-46c2-bdc0-cb1088d97327}
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i102: Detected related bundle: {7b178cda-9740-4701-a92a-f168d213b343}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.20.27508.1, operation: MajorUpgrade
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i103: Detected related package: {E493B8F4-E300-43EC-95D0-BDF3711297EA}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.27.29016.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i103: Detected related package: {F07B1E25-5670-4556-9C7F-5A1966C83269}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.27.29016.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i103: Detected related package: {E493B8F4-E300-43EC-95D0-BDF3711297EA}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.27.29016.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i103: Detected related package: {F07B1E25-5670-4556-9C7F-5A1966C83269}, scope: PerMachine, version: 14.27.29016.0, language: 0 operation: MajorUpgrade
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i101: Detected package: vcRuntime_arm64, state: Absent, cached: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.1' evaluates to true.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i200: Plan begin, 11 packages, action: Install
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64) AND NOT (Arm64_Check = "ARM64")' evaluates to true.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64) AND NOT (Arm64_Check = "ARM64")' evaluates to true.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i052: Condition 'Arm64_Check = "ARM64"' evaluates to false.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i201: Planned package: vcRuntime_arm64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i207: Planned related bundle: {7b178cda-9740-4701-a92a-f168d213b343}, type: Upgrade, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, dependency: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i300: Apply begin
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:37]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to get size of pseudo bundle: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{40d3fee2-b257-46c2-bdc0-cb1088d97327}\VC_redist.x64.exe
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]e000: Error 0x80070003: Failed to initialize package from related bundle id: {40d3fee2-b257-46c2-bdc0-cb1088d97327}
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i362: System restore disabled, system restore point not created.
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{8bdfe669-9705-4184-9368-db9ce581e0e7}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\WINDOWS\Temp\{47A954F9-450C-48B9-B703-EC95E7EE6A67}\.be\VC_redist.x64.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8bdfe669-9705-4184-9368-db9ce581e0e7}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: VC,redist.x64,amd64,14.36,bundle, version: 14.36.32532.0
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{8bdfe669-9705-4184-9368-db9ce581e0e7}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[4688:0880][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{D5D19E2F-7189-42FE-8103-92CD1FA457C2}v14.36.32532\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
[4688:0880][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i304: Verified existing payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{D5D19E2F-7189-42FE-8103-92CD1FA457C2}v14.36.32532\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
[4688:0880][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0025DD72-A959-45B5-A0A3-7EFEB15A8050}v14.36.32532\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
[4688:0880][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{0025DD72-A959-45B5-A0A3-7EFEB15A8050}v14.36.32532\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:22:38]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{D5D19E2F-7189-42FE-8103-92CD1FA457C2}v14.36.32532\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:23:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:23:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{8bdfe669-9705-4184-9368-db9ce581e0e7}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: VC,redist.x64,amd64,14.36,bundle
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i352: Removing cached bundle: {8bdfe669-9705-4184-9368-db9ce581e0e7}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8bdfe669-9705-4184-9368-db9ce581e0e7}\
[4688:1380][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{8bdfe669-9705-4184-9368-db9ce581e0e7}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x643
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: Arm64_Check = AMD64
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: VersionNT = 10.0.0.0
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: VersionNT64 = 10.0.0.0
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: windows_uCRT_DetectKey = 10.0.22000.1
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists = 1
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 5
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleFileVersion = 14.36.32532.0
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.log
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 = C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 = C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Microsoft Corporation
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.36.32532
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = D:\Aporimuse\VScommunity\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.36.32532,chip=x64\VC_redist.x64.exe
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder = D:\Aporimuse\VScommunity\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.36.32532,chip=x64\
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = VC,redist.x64,amd64,14.36,bundle
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 = C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 = C:\Users\86231\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20230607100413_348_Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessFolder = D:\Aporimuse\VScommunity\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.36.32532,chip=x64\
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleSourceProcessPath = D:\Aporimuse\VScommunity\Packages\Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest,version=14.36.32532,chip=x64\VC_redist.x64.exe
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 14.36.32532.0
[4598:10E8][2023-06-07T10:23:26]i007: Exit code: 0x643, restarting: No
```

there is the error code :'PackageId:Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest;PackageAction:Install;ReturnCode:1603;'